# How to handle KeyError(key)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, error-handling

```py
import pandas as pd

colnames = ['Date', 'Items', 'Quantity', 'Price']
df1 = pd.read_csv('data_assignment_1.txt',sep=" ",names=colnames, header=None)

print(df1)


Output:

         Date   Items  Quantity  Price

0  2020-09-23  Item_A         1    1.9
1  2020-09-23  Item_B         1    1.2
2  2020-09-23  Item_A         2    1.9
3  2020-09-23  Item_B         1    1.2
4  2020-09-24  Item_A         1    1.9
5  2020-09-24  Item_B         1    1.2
6  2020-09-24  Item_C         1    1.3
7  2020-09-25  Item_D         1    2.7
```

Now I groupby date and items to find the total Quantity:

```py
groupby_date_item = df1.groupby(['Date', 'Items'])['Quantity'].sum()

print(groupby_date_item['2020-09-23','Item_A'])

Output result:
 3
```

Now the problem is if i put Item D with the date 2020-09-23 I will get an error:

```py
print(groupby_date_item['2020-09-23','Item_D'])

Output result:
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: ('2020-09-23', 'Item_d')
```

How do I handle the error if item does not exist on that date or input wrong date and item?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and make an effort to properly format your code and output so that it is readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have discovered, you will get an Error if you try to retrieve a value that does not exist. One way to resolve this issue is to use a `try-except` clause.

See example below - where I use a custom function to handle the data retrieval using a try-except clause.
If the function generates an error, it will return `0`.

#### Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_Item(my_Date, my_Item, gb_date_item):
    try:
        total_sale = gb_date_item[my_Date, my_Item]
    except:
        total_sale = 0
        
    return f"Total Sale on: {my_Date} for {my_Item} : {total_sale}"

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': ['2020-09-23', '2020-09-23', '2020-09-23', '2020-09-23', '2020-09-24', '2020-09-24', '2020-09-24', '2020-09-25'],
                    'Items': ['Item_A', 'Item_B', 'Item_A', 'Item_B', 'Item_A', 'Item_B', 'Item_C', 'Item_D'],
                    'Quantity': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                    'Price': [1.9, 1.2, 1.9, 1.2, 1.9, 1.2, 1.3, 2.7]})

groupby_date_item = df1.groupby(['Date', 'Items'])['Quantity'].sum()

print(get_Item('2020-09-23', 'Item_A', groupby_date_item))
print(get_Item('2020-09-23', 'Item_B', groupby_date_item))
print(get_Item('2020-09-23', 'Item_D', groupby_date_item))
```

#### Output:

```
Total Sale on: 2020-09-23 for Item_A : 3
Total Sale on: 2020-09-23 for Item_B : 2
Total Sale on: 2020-09-23 for Item_D : 0
```

#### Note:

Replace `0` with whatever you want to show for when date is not found.

```
except:
        total_sale = 0  # Replace this value
```

Comment: Hi ScootC many thanks on your solution. I tried edit your code to have print out something like this: 
def get_Item(my_Date, my_Item, gb_date_item):
    try:
        result = print('Total Sale on:',my_Date, 'for',my_Item, ':' ,gb_date_item[my_Date, my_Item])
    except:
        result = 0

    return result



colnames = ['Date', 'Items', 'Quantity', 'Price']
df1 = pd.read_csv('data_assignment_1.txt',sep=" ",names=colnames, header=None)


groupby_date_item = df1.groupby(['Date', 'Items'])['Quantity'].sum()


print(get_Item('2020-09-23', 'Item_B', groupby_date_item))

Comment: Ok - that won't work - let me update my solution.

Comment: now the output result is Total Sale on: 2020-09-23 for Item_B : 2
None. any idea how to remove the none?

Comment: Date   Items  Quantity  Price
0  2020-09-23  Item_A         1    1.9
1  2020-09-23  Item_B         1    1.2
2  2020-09-23  Item_A         2    1.9
3  2020-09-23  Item_B         1    1.2
4  2020-09-24  Item_A         1    1.9
5  2020-09-24  Item_B         1    1.2
6  2020-09-24  Item_C         1    1.3
7  2020-09-25  Item_D         1    2.7

Comment: above is my csv file

Comment: What do you want it to print when there is an error or if the data does not exist.

Comment: maybe result not found or do have any suggestion?

Comment: what i want to achieve is read the csv file and input the parameter of the date and item to find to have the output like this: Total sale: 2020-09-23 for item A: 3.

Comment: So if it does not find it, it will show : `Total Sale on: 2020-09-23 for Item_D : 0` ??

Comment: yes if date does not exist then show something date not found

Comment: Thanks for the update!! one more question what is f"Total Sale on: {my_Date} for {my_Item} : {total_sale}" the f is for what purpose when i remove it will not show the result

Comment: The `f` turns the string into an `f-string` : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: f-strings allow you to insert your variables into your strings directly.

Comment: Thank again!! I will try to read up and understand it as i'm trying to learn python programming

Comment: Hi ScottC can i trouble you again on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75433364/how-to-have-all-the-results-using-beautifulsoup-with-selenium-and-disable-the-au?noredirect=1#comment133100277_75433364

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative where you check for the key. In simple terms direct to your question, you would just use `if ('2020-09-23', 'Item_D') in groupby_date_item: ...`

This is a more complete example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({

    "Date":['2020-09-23','2020-09-23','2020-09-25'],
    "Items":['Item_A','Item_A','Item_D'],
    "Quantity":[1,1,1]
})

g = df1.groupby(['Date','Items'])['Quantity'].sum()

for tup in [('2020-09-23', 'Item_A'), ('2020-09-23', 'Item_D')]:
    if tup in g.index:
        print(f'{str(tup)}: {g[tup]}')
    else:
        print(f'{str(tup)}: not found')
```