# How to have all the results using beautifulsoup with selenium and disable the automate test page?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to web scraping the website somehow it only show 24 results how to I load all result with hidden automate test page?

Below the code:

```py
    # import library
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
    import pandas as pd
    import bs4


    #create list
    items = []
    prices = []
    volumes = []


    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.fairprice.com.sg/category/milk-powder")
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    allelem = soup.find_all('div',class_='sc-1plwklf-0 iknXK product-container')

    #read all element
    for item in allelem:
      items.append(item.find('span', class_='sc-1bsd7ul-1 eJoyLL').text.strip())
  
    #read price
    for price in allelem:
      prices.append(price.find('span', class_='sc-1bsd7ul-1 sc-1svix5t-1 gJhHzP biBzHY').text.strip())


    #read volume
    for volume in allelem:
      volumes.append(volume.find('span', class_='sc-1bsd7ul-1 eeyOqy').text.strip())

    print(items)
    print(volumes)
    print(prices)

    #create dataframe
    final_array = []
    for item,price,volume in zip(items,prices,volumes):
     final_array.append({'Item':item,'Volume':volume,'Price':price})
    
    # covert to excel
    df = pd.DataFrame(final_array)
    print(df)
    df.to_excel('ntucv4milk.xlsx',index=False)
```

end of code

Comment: scroll the viewport down until you get no more updates and then pass the stuff to BS..  If you need to google more details, you are looking for how to handle lazy loading with selenium.

Comment: Hi @ Rasjani, I been trying google for it somehow can't find the way to resolve it and also to hide the automate test page

Comment: You may need to introduce some pseudo random wait times between each action to prevent being seen as a bot or pay for the captcha help(websites that solve captchas use humans and have an API). Captcha is not easy to get around but there is some threads on this very forum with some suggestions. No one knows a foolproof way of avoiding captcha.

Comment: I think the problem is the site only loaded new element when scroll down it will load new element. I still not find how to make it auto scrollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to define three lists (items, prices, volumes) which are going to incrementally grow by scrolling down the page. If you have a list `elements` of webelements, you can easily scroll to the last one by running

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', elements[-1])
```

Then all you have to do is wait until new items are loaded and then add them to the three lists. If no items are loaded in a given amount of time (`max_wait`, which is 10 seconds), then probably there are no more items to load and we can break the loop.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chromedriver_path = '...'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path))

driver.get('https://www.fairprice.com.sg/category/milk-powder')

items, prices, volumes = [], [], []
c = 0 # counter
max_wait = 10
no_new_items = False

while 1:
    items_new = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="product-name-and-metadata"] > span[weight="normal"]')
    items   += [item.text.strip()  for item  in items_new[c:]]
    prices  += [price.text.strip() for price in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="product"] span[weight="black"]')[c:]]
    volumes += [vol.text.strip()   for vol   in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="product-name-and-metadata"] div>span:first-child')[c:]]
    counter = len(items)
    print(counter,'items scraped',end='\r')
    
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', items_new[-1])

    items_loaded = items_new.copy()
    start = time.time()
    # wait up to `max_wait` seconds for new elements to be loaded
    while len(items_new) == len(items_loaded):
        items_loaded = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="product-name-and-metadata"] > span[weight="normal"]')
        if time.time() - start > max_wait:
            no_new_items = True
            break
    if no_new_items:
        break

pd.DataFrame({'item':items,'price':prices,'volume':volumes})
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Hi Sound Wave, do you mind shared me the full list of code? Cos I tried copy the above code I getting some error which I do not understand. Also how do I disable the test automate page while running the code. Many thks in advance

Comment: @jjbkd I updated the answer adding the complete code, check it out! What do you mean with "test automate page"?

Comment: many thanks what i mean is chrome broswer when you run the code the browser will auto run to simulate the scrolling. Yes i have copied the code but how do i set the path i tried this  chromedriver_path = 'C:\\Users\\jjbkd\\Desktop\\Python_Webscraper\\ but it does not work. thks

Comment: @jjbkd try to replace `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path))` with `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` and let me know

Comment: yes is able to run after i change this back to my old code:import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

#chromedriver_path = 'C:\\Users\\jjbkd\\Desktop\\Python_Webscraper\\'
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path))

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

Comment: but how do i hide the browser while running the code

Comment: @jjbkd While the script is running you can switch window and do something else, you mean this? Or you want a headless browser?

Comment: yes headless browser that what i mean I tried many way it cant work so i don't know how to do it

Comment: @jjbkd You have to run this `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()` then `options.add_argument("--headless=new")` and finally `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)`

Comment: you are great it worked!!! Many thanks on this by the way do you have any recommend python site or book for beginner cos im trying to learn python some site is too hard to understand

Comment: @jjbkd look here you find many good free courses https://www.coursera.org/search?query=python

Comment: noted with many thanks

Comment: Hi @soundwave sorry trouble you again could you explain these code what does it stand for "span[weight="normal"] ,"span[weight="black"]', ">span:first-child'" and print(counter,'items scraped',end='\r') Im trying to figure your code can't find on google thks

Comment: @jjbkd `span[weight="normal"]` targets [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uPls.png) kind of span, similarly for the one with `weight=black`. To understand `>span:first-child` you can check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php). Lastly, about `print(counter,'items scraped',end='\r')` I guess you don't know what `end='\r'` is, well it simply moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, so that the following print will overwrite the previous print. Try to remove `,end='\r'` and see what happens

Comment: Thanks again @soundwave I will read up the link and test removing the end='\r'